# Fill this 5x5 number grid incrementally, either by moving two boxes diagonally or moving three boxes in a row or column

Tags: logical-deduction

One day, a friend has shown me a 5 by 5 grid, challenging me to fill it with numbers from 1 to 25.
Obviously, it is not simple because there are some rules:

- The number 1 is placed in the center of the grid
- The numbers are placed in ascending order, either by moving two boxes diagonally or moving three boxes in a row or column (as shown in diagram)

[image: 5 by 5 grid showing possible moves]

How can you achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "in ascending order"? In which direction?

Comment: And what do these "movements" have to do with filling the grid?

Comment: You have to fill the grid with numbers from 1 to 25.
You start with the 1 in the center of the grid and you place the others numbers in an ascending order by moving two boxes diagonally or three boxes linearly.
Sorry for the lack of precision, it's my first question.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Now I'm sure I've seen this puzzle here before quite recently, but I can't find it! +1 anyway.

Comment: What is the significance of "i" and "i+1"?

Comment: They represent the available boxes to place the number i+1 with respect to the number i. It's an example.

Comment: In other words you have to find a knight's tour on the 5x5 chessboard, except that you have to start in the centre, and instead of a knight you have a piece that can do move of the type {0,+-3}, {+-3,0}, and {+-2, +-2}.

Comment: Yeah, something like that.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it :)

Comment: There is no "correct" answer, only different ways to solve the problem and they are all equivalent. I mostly post this question so that people can have fun solving it. But if I really have to validate an answer, I think I'll validate the first one that has been posted.

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt Puzzles with no "right" answer are generally discouraged; you should have some objective criteria, even if arbitrary, for determining the "best" or most "right" answer, so that we're not just assembling a collection of alternate answers.  In the case of multiple people giving essentially equivalent answers, most people choose to Accept the answer that is the most complete, direct, or simple to understand; or if there's no particular standout on those grounds, the answer that was posted first.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis, Alix: it's not exactly a knight's tour because a) there's nothing explicitly to prevent two successive diagonal moves, although on a 5x5 topology that's impossible because the center is already filled b) that's moving two boxes *diagonally*, not orthogonally. But yeah, roughly like a knight's tour

Comment: To avoid overcounting rotationally and axially symmetric solutions, why don't we WLOG say that 2 has to go in the TL corner, and hence 3 in the top row?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely not unique, but here's one solution:

> \begin{array} & 2 & 17 & 20 & 3 & 16 \\ 12 & 23 & 6 & 13 & 22 \\ 19 & 9 & 1 & 18 & 8 \\ 5 & 14 & 21 & 4 & 15 \\ 11 & 24 & 7 & 10 & 25 \end{array}

Found entirely with trial and error.

Comment: Gratz, I calculated with computer there are 352 possible solutions.

Comment: @shyos: Are there any solutions where you can jump from the $25$ back to the $1$?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Sure.  Just swap the 23 and 25 in this solution.

Comment: To avoid overcounting rotationally and axially symmetric solutions, why don't we WLOG say that 2 has to go in the TL corner, and hence 3 in the top row?

Answer (score 2):

found another solution by trial and error

> \begin{array} & 23 & 17 & 5 & 22 & 16 \\ 12 & 20 & 25 & 13 & 3 \\ 6 & 9 & 1 & 18 & 8 \\ 24 & 14 & 4 & 21 & 15 \\ 11 & 19 & 7 & 10 & 2 \end{array}

I kinda just made "boxes" where I could and used diagonals to transition the progression to the next "box"

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed very similar to a KT (knight's tour). It is necessary to change the move rules, as a proper KT on a 5x5 grid is nearly trivial for an open path, and impossible for a closed path.

I was introduced to the problem in 2017, and became quite fascinated by it - so much that I wrote a program to find all solutions. It found (just as shyos pointed out) that there are 352 solutions when starting in the center (the problem as presented to me stipulated that the starting position could be anywhere on the grid). Of the 352 solutions, 96 were closed paths. By analyzing the program's results I was able to establish a fixed order to try for each successive move that will always lead to a closed path solution from any starting position, with no trial and error (backtracking) needed. If there is still any interest, I can post my algorithm. Here is one (closed path) solution for the center start position:

```
25 17  7 24 16
12  4 21 13  5
19  9  1 18  8
22 14  6 23 15
11  3 20 10  2
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1

> Name the cells.
>
>  [image]

Step 2

> Make a graph of the possible moves.
>
>  [image]

Step 3

> Rearrange the nodes.
>
>  [image]
>
>  I removed the M.
>  M connects to all four corners.
>  Since we must start at M and then move to a corner
>  we might as well start from the corner.

Step 4

> Quite easily find a path visiting all nodes.
>  We must start from a corner and might as well end at another corner to reconnect to M.
>
>  [image]
>
>  I was surprised to see how few moves remain unused.

Step 5

> We now have the sequence: MAPSDLOWHTEBQIXUFRCKNVGJY.
>  Go back to "square 1" and number the cells accordingly.
>
>  [image]